# ngif with a form inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I use a **ngRepeat** directive to show data of persons (now I am showing only the name of the persons).

The name of the person is shown using a **span** tag.
Also there is a button that hide the **span** and show an **input field** containg the name of the person so it can be editable.

When I press a button I need the affected **span** to be "converted" to **input**, but it's not working and all the **spans** are converted to **inputs**.

```
    <div ng-repeat="a_person in persons.data track by $index">

        <md-button aria-label="Show inputs">
            <md-icon ng-click="showInput(a_person)">edit</md-icon>
        </md-button>

        <span  ng-if="!a_person.editMode">{{a_person.name}}</span>
        <input ng-if= "a_person.editMode" type="text" value="{{a_person.name}}">

    </div>
```

I am using a table and a form but I don't show them here so it can be easy to explain.

Comment: @KarthikVU what difference would that make?

Comment: Show the code for `showInput()` and provide a [mcve] in plunker or codepen or any other sandbox

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep an array of Boolean to keep track of showing an input field or span for each item in your `ng-repeat`.

```
$scope.showEdit = new Array(n)

$scope.showInput(index) {
   $scope.showEdit[index] = !$scope.showEdit[index];
}
```

and finally

```
<span  ng-if="!showEdit[$index]">{{a_person.name}}</span>
<input ng-if= "!showEdit[$index]" type="text" value="{{a_person.name}}">
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, since the OP keeps the edit mode of each person in the person itself (which is a much better idea, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="a_person in persons.data track by $index">

    <md-button aria-label="Show inputs">
        <!-- REPLACE
        <md-icon ng-click="showInput(a_person)">edit</md-icon>
        -->
        <!-- WITH this --> 
        <md-icon ng-click="a_person.editMode = true">edit</md-icon>
    </md-button>

    <span  ng-hide="a_person.editMode">{{a_person.name}}</span>
    <!--
    <input ng-if="a_person.editMode" type="text" value="{{a_person.name}}">
    -->
    <!-- USE ng-model directive -->
    <input ng-show="a_person.editMode" type="text" ng-model="a_person.name">

</div>
```

I recommend using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` because the `ng-if` directive creates a child scope which will fight with the `ng-model` directive which expects no scope on that element. Also `ng-if` has much more overhead because it compiles/destroys DOM while the other changes only CSS style.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work as per your expectations :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = {
      "data": [
        {
          id:1,
          name:"name1"
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name:"name2"
        },
        {
          id:3,
          name:"name3"
        }
      ]
    };
    
    $scope.showInput = function(personid) {
      $scope.editperid = personid;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="person in persons.data">
            <a ng-click="showInput(person.id)">edit</a>
        <span ng-hide="editperid == person.id">{{person.name}}</span>
         <input ng-show="editperid == person.id" type="text" value="{{person.name}}">
    </div>
</div>
```